# Closest point from List for every point of other List

Tags: c++, coordinates

I have a population of so called "Dots" that search for food. Every Dot has a sight_ value, which indicates the range in which it can see food.
The position of each Dot is saved as a `pair<uint16_t,uint16_t>`. The positions of all foodsources are in a `vector<pair<uint16_t,uint16_t>>`.

Now I want to calculate the closest foodsource for every Dot, which this Dot can see. And I don't want to calculate the distance of every combination.

My idea was to create a copy of the food-vector, sort one copy by x and the other by y. Then find the interval [x-sight, x+sight] respectively [y-sight, y+sight] in the vectors and then create the intersection of both.
I've read over set_intersection, but it requires both ranges to be sorted with the same rule.

Any Ideas how I could do this? Could also be that my Idea is just the wrong approach.

Thanks
IceFreez3r

Edit:
I did some runtime approximations:
Sort Food: n log n
Find Interval for one Coordinate and one Dot: 2 log n (lower and upper bound)
If we assume equal distribution of food sources, we can calculate the bound that is estimated to be closer to the middle first and then calculate the second bound in the rest interval. This would reduce the runtime to: log n + log(n/2) *(Just realized this s probably not *that* powerful:log(n/2) =~ log(n) - 1)*
Build intersection: #x * #y =~ (n * sight/testgroundsize)^2
Compute exact Distance for every Food in Intersection: n * (sight/testgroundsize)^2

Sum: 2 n log n + 2 * #Dots * (log n + log(n/2) + (n * sight/testgroundsize)^2 + n * (sight/testgroundsize)^2)
Sum with just limiting one coordinate: n log n + #Dots * (log n + log(n/2) + n * sight/testgroundsize)

I did some tests and just calculated the above formulas on the run:

```
int dots = dots_.size();
int sum = 2 * n * log(n) + 2 * dots * (log(n) + log(n/2) + pow(n * (sum_sight / dots) / testground_size_,2) + n * pow((sum_sight / dots) / testground_size_, 2));
int sum2 = n * log(n) + dots * (log(n) + log(n/2) + n * (sum_sight / dots) / testground_size_);
cout << n*dots << endl << sum << endl << sum2 << endl;
```

It turned out the Intersection idea is just bad. While the idea of just limiting one coordinate is at least better than brute-force.
I didn't think about the grid-idea yet @Daniel Jour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're stepping into a whole field of interesting approaches to this problem. Terms to Google are binary space partitioning, quadtrees, ... and of course nearest neighbour search.

A relatively simple but effective approach when the dots are far more spread than what their "visible range" is:

1. Select a value "grid size".
2. Create a map from grid coordinates to a list/set of entities
3. For each food source:  put them in the map at their grid coordinates
4. For each dot: put them in the map at their grid coordinates *and* also in the neighbour grid "cells". The size of the neighbourhood depends on the grid size and the dot's sight value
5. For each entry in the map which contains at least one dot: Either do this algorithm recursively with a smaller grid size or use the brute force approach: check each dot in that grid cell against each food source in that grid cell.

This is a linear algorithm, compared with the quadratic brute force approach.

Calculation of grid coordinates: `grid_x = int(x / grid_size)` ... same for other coordinate.

Neighbourhood: `steps = ceil(sight_value / grid_size)` .. the neighbourhood is a square with side length `2×steps + 1` centred at the dot's grid coordinates

Answer (score 1):

I believe your approach is incorrect. This can be mathematically verified. What you can do instead is calculate the magnitude of the vector joining the dot with the food source by means of Pythagoras theorem, and ensure that this magnitude is less than the observation limit. This deals exclusively with determining relative distance, as defined by the Cartesian co-ordinate system, and the standard unit of measurement. In relation to efficiency concerns, the first order of business is to determine if the approach to be taken is in computational terms in actuality less efficient, as measured by time, even though the logical component responsible for certain calculations are, in virtue of this alternative implementation, less time consuming. Of coarse, the ideal is one in which the time taken is decreased, and not merely numerically contained by means of refactoring. 
Now, if it is the case that the position of a dot can be specified as any two numbers one may choose, this of course implies a frame of reference called the basis, and also one local to the dot in question. With respect to both, one can quantify position, and other such characteristics and properties. As a consequence of this observation, it would seem that you need n*2 data structures, where n is the amount of dots in the environment, that
contain the sorted values relative to each dot, and quite frankly it is unclear whether or not this approach would even work or is optimal. You state the design and programmatic constraint that the solution shall not compute the distances from each dot to each food source. But to achieve this, one must implement other such procedures, in order that we derive the correct results. These comments are made in relation to my discussion on efficiency. Therefore, you may be better of simply calculating the distance in each case. This is somewhat elegant.

Comment: I don't get what data structures you mean. But to summarize, you think that my approach is slower and I should use Brute-Force instead, right?